# Do I need a Canadian transit visa when I have a visitor visa?

Tags: visas, canada, transit-visas

I am a citizen of India and currently have a Canadian visitor visa that expires in 2018. I currently live in the US. My flight plan at the end of this year from US to India involves a layover in Canada for a couple of hours. Do I still need a transit visa or is my visitor visa enough?

Comment: Do you have a green card?

Answer (score 12):

No, nope, never. You do not need a transit visa. Visit visas are superior to transit visas. If you have a valid visit visa you can certainly transit through.

If you are eligible to apply to **enter** a country on its border (which you are) you are certainly eligible to apply for a **transit** through it.

As noted in the comment below, if you have only a single entry visa then its for you to decide whether you want to use that entry or apply for a transit visa because if you use a single entry visa for a transit it will still be called **USED**. However for Canada and many other countries visit visas are multiple entry usually.

Let's say any future reader has a Green Card and no Canadian Visa they can obtain an eTA online quickly to transit through Canada.

Comment: The problem that arises, however, is when you have a single-entry visa -- wasting that on a transit would be regrettable. We have a question on here somewhere asking about a Chinese single-entry visa and how to TWOV so as to not use up the single-entry. (Not sure it *that* one was ever resolved.)

Comment: Canadian Single entry visas are rare these days

Comment: You specified "a country", not "Canada". General answers are cool but you have to talk about the edge cases that might not apply to the specific country in question. :) (Also 'rare' implies 'still happens on occasion'. I don't know anything about Canadian visas, tho.)